# Official site - CXF Apache - CORS Example - Ambiguos

Tags: apache, cors, cxf, ambiguous

Anyone from Apache who could help me in the CORS example in your site?

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-cors.html#JAX-RSCORS-Examples

The example from this pages is a little ambiguous because the "address='/rest'" does not point to any resource "rest".

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services are exposed on url "/rest", so resources are avalible at paths like "/rest/delete".